# LINQ: sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, linq, fileopendialog

i have error sequence contains no element on below line

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Multiselect = true;
            dialog.Filter =
                loaders
                .Select(loader => string.Format("{0}|{1}", loader.Metadata.Alias, loader.Metadata.ExtensionFilter))
                .Aggregate((f1, f2) => f1 + "|" + f2);
            dialog.Filter += "|All Files|*.*";
```

Comment: where do you get *loaders*? probably it is empty

Comment: second that. LINQ looks fine. plus, in case `loaders` is empty, you would end up with an extra pipe | in front of the "All Files" part

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overload of [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) you're using will throw an exception if the sequence contains no elements.  You can use the overload that takes a 'seed' argument: this will just return the seed if there are no elements.

```
loaders
    .Select(loader => string.Format("{0}|{1}", loader.Metadata.Alias, loader.Metadata.ExtensionFilter))
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (f1, f2) => f1 + "|" + f2);
```

Better still would be to ditch aggregate altogether - you're potentially allocating lots of strings you're throwing away before you get to your result.  Just use `string.Join`:

```
var loaderFilters = loaders.Select(loader 
     => string.Format("{0}|{1}", loader.Metadata.Alias, loader.Metadata.ExtensionFilter));

var allFilters = loaderFilters.Concat(new []{"All Files|*.*"});

dialog.Filter = string.Join("|", allFilters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified to:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Multiselect = true;
dialog.Filter = string.Join("|", loaders.Select(loader => loader.Metadata.Alias + "|" + loader.Metadata.ExtensionFilter)) + "|All Files|*.*";
```